# How to declare nested components in Angular2

Tags: angular, components

In the [Angular2 tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) a detail component is introduced by adding it to the `@NgModule`.

Instead, I would like to add it by the outer component (`AppComponent`) somehow importing it, so that only the outer component refers to the inner component.

I can't figure out how to do it. Old examples refer to the `directives` property, but `directives` no longer exist in the type `ComponentMetadtaType`. So this does not work

```js
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    [..]
    directives: [HeroDetailComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add directives and components to `declarations: []` of a module.
If you want to only one component to be able to use a component, create a module that consists only of these two components.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, FooComponent, BarDirective],
  ...
})
```

Comment: You may be right, but you're essentially saying that what I want to do is not possible to do in the way I want to?

Comment: I explained what "somehow importing it" can look like. In Angular2 final you are required to use modules and it's the only way to make one component, directive or pipe known to another component.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn That's not exactly what he is saying. It's true that you cannot declare a component in another component. So the declaration should be moved to an outer module, which will still be fine because other modules/components will not know about this outer module, it's exactly as your old outer component declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You should **declare** it with **declarations metadata** as shown below,

```
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,HeroDetailComponent],   //<----here
  providers:    [],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: That is not they way I want to do it. I'd like to declaratively import the inner component in the outer component that is using the inner component. The  `@NgModule` declaration does not make clear what is using what. But maybe what I want is impossible.